# Running gl-env to install Graphlab : gl-env is a directory

Tags: python, command, package, installation, graphlab

I'm trying to install GraphLab Create using commandline, following instructions from [turi.com](https://turi.com/download/install-graphlab-create-command-line.html).

```
$ conda create -n gl-env python=3.6
WARNING: A space was detected in your requested environment path
'C:\Users\PARVATHY SARAT\Anaconda3\envs\gl-env'
Spaces in paths can sometimes be problematic.

Fetching package metadata ...........
Solving package specifications: .

Package plan for installation in environment C:\Users\PARVATHY SARAT\Anaconda3\envs\gl-env:

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    certifi:        2016.2.28-py36_0
    pip:            9.0.1-py36_1
    python:         3.6.2-0
    setuptools:     36.4.0-py36_0
    vs2015_runtime: 14.0.25420-0
    wheel:          0.29.0-py36_0
    wincertstore:   0.2-py36_0

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

vs2015_runtime 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:20 100.25 kB/s
python-3.6.2-0 100% |###############################| Time: 0:07:48  70.55 kB/s
certifi-2016.2 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:01 119.28 kB/s
wincertstore-0 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00 144.15 kB/s
setuptools-36. 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:07  78.01 kB/s
#
# To activate this environment, use:
# > activate gl-env
#
# To deactivate an active environment, use:
# > deactivate
#
# * for power-users using bash, you must source
#
```

Now, trying to activate the environment :

```
$ '/c/Users/PARVATHY SARAT/Anaconda3/envs/gl-env' activate gl-env
bash: /c/Users/PARVATHY SARAT/Anaconda3/envs/gl-env: Is a directory
```

Which file in gl-env directory should I source? Trying to install graphlab using license yields the following message :

```
Collecting graphlab-create>=2.1 (from GraphLab-Create-License==2.1)
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement graphlab-create>=2.1 (from GraphLab-Create-License==2.1) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for graphlab-create>=2.1 (from GraphLab-Create-License==2.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Turi's Graphlab download tutorial we only need to have : Python 2.7.x environment and pip version >= 7 and Anaconda2 v4.0.0 (64-bit). IPython Notebook is recommended.

Comment: I have Python 3.6, Anaconda3, IPython and pip 9.0. Am I supposed to source to a particular file in the gl-env directory in the activate command?